# Are circular unit references in the uses list possible in delphi?

Tags: c, delphi

I am translating some C header files to Delphi.
In those header files, two files share their struct with each other.
When I tried this in Delphi, it gave me circular reference error.
So I am currently writing both header's translation in single .pas file.
Is there any other way to get around this problem?

This is a small example.
The actual header files are more complicated :\

==File1.h==

```
struct a
{
int data;
}
int compare(struct a,struct b);
```

==File2.h==

```
struct b
{
int data;
}
int compare(struct A,struct b);
```

==File1.pas==

```
uses File2;
type
  a = packed record
    data: Integer;
  end;

compare = function(d1: a; d2: b): Integer; cdecl;
```

==File2.pas==

```
uses File1;
type
  b = packed record
    data: Integer;
  end;

compare = function(d1: a; d2: b): Integer; cdecl;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Eugene points out circular interface unit references are not possible in Delphi. There are a few possible solutions:

- Move the shared struct to a third unit and let the other two units include this unit.
- Move one of the unit references to the `implementation` section (if this is possible).
- Keep all in one file as you mention

Note that the fact that Delphi forces you to think about circular references is not a bad thing IMHO. In many cases, these circular references draw your attention to a flaw in your design.

Comment: I often find that the appearance of a "circular reference" situation in my code is the sign that my units have poor cohesion, and unnecessarily high coupling. In other words, move the shared struct (or whatever is really needed to be shared among all these units) to its own small unit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can't make the units reference each other in "interface" section. Move "uses" clause of one file to implementation section. This is a limitation of pascal.

Comment: Is it a limitation of **Pascal** or is it a limitation of the **Delphi** pascal compiler? I know there's no multi-pass pascal compiler, but I don't think there's anything in the language that would actually stop one from building an multi-pass compiler.

Comment: @Cosmin: who would want one though? I for one like the single pass compiler's speed and would not give that up just for the sake of being able to use circular references in the interface section. Especially as I feel that circular references are to be avoided as much as possible anyway. It is one reason I only use the implementation section's uses clause for units that need it specifically because of circular references. That way these are at least somewhat explicit...

Comment: @Cosmin there are several flavors of Pascal. Original pascal had fixed order of type, const and other declarations and didn't include units at all, if memory serves. So it's hard to say, whose limitation is this.

Comment: @Cosmin: Pascal didn't have interface/implementation keywords at all so this is definitely a limitation of the single pass Delphi compiler.

Comment: @gabr, borland/turbo pascal has units from version 3 or 4. So it included interface and implementation keywords.  Standard (Wirth) pascal didn't have those.

Comment: ISO (7185:1990) Pascal does not have the `uses` keyword - everything is in one file...

Comment: @Gamecat: I was refering to standard/original Pascal.

Comment: The whole goal of the Pascal language was to be able to develop single-pass compilers for it for two reasons: much simpler grammar, and much faster compile times. Back in the time Wirth designed Pascal, CPU usage was really expensive. That design is still very much reflected in Delphi. Now it is nice that KISS still applies to the Delphi language, and that the compiler runs circles around many other languages' compilers.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund et al, Delphi is no longer single-pass.

Comment: It is not truly multi-pass either.  (@WormRegards)

Comment: @Worm Regards, do you have a link for `Delphi is no longer single-pass`?

Comment: No, but google have. As Warren P said, 209+ addition equals to preprocessor pass in normal modular build, to resolve all of angle brackets

Comment: @CosminPrund, here is link to a comment from @dthorpe, [`Forward reference not allowed?`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!msg/borland.public.delphi.language.objectpascal/70nfJsmXrjM/br4TSntE-TQJ). Delphi has a multipass architecture compiler.